# No keyboard after reset!

Tags: sms

I don't know how it happened but I did a factory reset on my LG g pad and it came back with no keyboard   Which means I can't pass the setup wizard because I can't type a password.  I can't go anywhere?! I didn't delete the keyboard so I am wondering what happened.  Just need help!!

Comment: you should be able to sideload apk from recovery, or connect physical keyboard with OTG